# How to handle syntax Errors

Tags: python

So, we had instance in the past where code were broken in IOT devices because of syntax errors.

While there is exception handling in the code. I wanted to create a script to check and make sure that the codes compiles and run without syntax error, else the script replace the broken code by an earlier version.

I tried this

```
from delta_script import get_update
def test_function():
    try:
        get_update()
    except SyntaxError as syntaxError:
        replace_script("utility.py", syntaxError)
    except Exception as ignored:
        pass
```

However the problem it when it hit a SyntaxError, it just throw it on the screen and `replace_script`
because the exception happens on `delta_script.py` from which `get_update()` was imported.

So what's the solution in this case?

I have also another function

```
def compile():
    try:
        for file in compile_list:
            py_compile.compile(file)
    except Exception as exception:
        script_heal(file, exception)
```

however in this one, it never report any exception, because I go and introduce syntaxError and the code still compile without reporting an error

Any one could help me figure out a better way to solve those two problems?
thanks,

Comment: Why not fix the `SyntaxError` instead of catching it?

Comment: We always do, however if any unfortunate situation happens, we would like to be able to recover from it.

Comment: `SyntaxError` is a problem in code(except you run code string which is input by user). So usually it is not to be handled, it should be fixed.

Comment: You can catch runtime errors only. A syntax error is no runtime error.

Comment: To be fairly honnest, if your deployment process cannot catch a `SyntaxError`, you have more urgent problems than that error. A syntax error happens *before run-time* by definition. It's literally impossible to miss if you just do `python your_script` before deployment. Or do you import dynamicly generated scripts for some reason?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in your deployment process and you need some sort of QA/test/compilation/build step in there which ensures such basic things. What does your current process look like…?

Answer (score 1):

`SyntaxError`s occur at compile time, not run time, so you generally can't catch them. There are exceptions, involving run time compilation using `eval`/`exec`, but in general, `except SyntaxError:` is nonsensical; something goes wrong *compiling* the code before it can *run* the code that sets up the `try/except` to catch the error.

The solution is to not write syntactically invalid code, or if you must write it (e.g. to allow newer Python syntax only when supported) to evaluate strings of said code dynamically with `eval` (often wrapping `compile` if you need something more complicated than a single expression) or `exec`.

Comment: can you please give an example on how this can be done? the wrapping?

Comment: @DavidShapero: Examples exist already. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483373/364696).